# Porting Windows platform C++ to POSIX (Linux) C++ - WSAGetLastError()

Tags: c++, linux, error-handling, porting

I am currently porting some Windows mobile C++ code to standard C++.

So I am trying to find alternatives for windows specific functions.

I have had very little luck in finding a standard C++ function that can help me replace the WSAGetLastError() windows specific function.

WSAGetLastError() returns error numbers for errors that occur with sockets in windows.

So I was wondering if anyone was aware of a way to replace this function in standard c++?

A way to get different error numbers for different outcomes of connecting/dissconecting a socket would be sufficent.

Comment: There's no such thing as "Windows C++", and you're not trying to port to "Standard C++" either. You're trying to port your program from a Windows platform to a POSIX platform. Neither one has anything much to do with standard C++.

Comment: You should notice that the documentation for all the socket functions tells you where they store their error information. For example: http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind. You'll be reading all that documentation anyway because socket functions work differently on different operating systems. Socket functions on Linux don't necessarily behave the same as functions with the same names on Windows. Pay close attention to corner cases.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, much appreciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are no Standard C++ functions supporting sockets. However, the POSIX socket functions should all set the `errno` variable on error - you just need to examine this - it should be declared in `errno.h`.

Comment: If you are using non-blocking connects, then you will also need to use `getsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, ...);` to get the `connect()` status.  And be aware that `errno` is not changed on successful operations - so you may want to specifically set it to zero before each operation.

Comment: Setting errno to zero is not good practice. You should instead only examine it if the function call return value indicates an error.

Answer (score 1):

I would port to Boost.ASIO which will abstract networking differences and likely give you better performance by using asynchronous calls and overlapped IO.  When you are done you code will work everywhere boost works.